# Spring Boot Request body validation on same DTO used for different API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my request body DTO, I want specific fields to be required for one of the API but not for another.

My request body:

```java
@Data
class MyClass {
    
    @NotNull
    private String fullName;
    
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
}
```

I want `fullName` to be required for `/api/v1` but not for `/api/v2`. I am using `@Valid` on request body from `javax.validation`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Spring's `@Validated`, which is a variant of JSR-303's `@Valid`.  This is used at the method-level:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "apiV1Method")
public String apiV1Method(@Validated(Account. ValidationAPI1.class) MyClassDTO myClassDTO) {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "apiV2Method")
public String apiV2Method(@Validated(Account. ValidationAPI2.class) MyClassDTO myClassDTO) {...}
```

**Object:**

```java
class MyClassDTO {

    public interface ValidationAPI1 {}
    public interface ValidationAPI2 {}

    @NotNull(groups = {ValidationAPI1.class})
    private String fullName;

    @NotNull(groups = {ValidationAPI1.class, ValidationAPI2.class})
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(groups = {ValidationAPI1.class, ValidationAPI2.class})
    private String lastName;

    ...
}
```